# how to select a dropdown value in selenium webdriver using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I have following HTML structure:

```html
<button class="dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" data-id="strategic_reseller_country" title="United States">
<div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 245.6px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 40px;">
   <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu" style="max-height: 243.6px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 38px;">
      <li class="" rel="0">
         <a class="" style="" tabindex="0">
         <span class="text"/>
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"/>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li rel="1">
         <a class="" style="" tabindex="0">
         <span class="text">Andorra</span>
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"/>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li rel="2">
         <a class="" style="" tabindex="0">
         <span class="text">United Arab Emirates</span>
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"/>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li rel="3">
         <a class="" style="" tabindex="0">
         <span class="text">Afghanistan</span>
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"/>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li rel="4">
      <li rel="5">
      <li rel="6">
      <li rel="7">
      <li rel="8">
      <li rel="9">
         <a class="" style="" tabindex="0">
         <span class="text">Netherlands Antilles</span>
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"/>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So how could I get the item from list?

I am new to `Node.Js` (JavaScript) so I don't know how to achieve it in `node.Js` but it can be achieved in java as follows :

```js
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.class("dropdown-menu inner selectpicker"))); 
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Andorra");
```

Comment: Node doesn't really have any way to parse HTML, but you could take a look at something like [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cheerio) and use something very similar to jQuery syntax to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) for this.

```
module.exports = {
    "login": function (browser) {
        var cheerio = require("cheerio")

        browser
            .url("http://www.wikipedia.org")
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .waitForElementVisible('select#searchLanguage', 1000)
            .source(function(result) { // .source() dump the page source in the variable
                $ = cheerio.load(result.value)
                var num_languages = $('select#searchLanguage option').length
                console.log('Wikipedia.org Languages: ' + num_languages);
            })
            .end();
    }
};
```

or simply using the `.execute()` command

Comment: Out of the track!! answer

Comment: what do you pass to the function as 'browser'?

Answer (score 13):

Just click the desired option.

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#mySelection > option:nth-child(4)'))
    .click();
```

or by value

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#mySelection > option[value=apple]'))
    .click();
```

Note that I've changed your 'By' to a css selector. I'm lazy and like to just drill into the option from developer tools and select Copy CSS Path (chrome) or Copy Unique Selector (firefox).

Answer (score 9):

You can create a function that select the value you desire

like this...

```
driver.wait(
    until.elementLocated(By.id("continents")), 20000
).then(element => {
    selectByVisibleText(element, "Africa")
});

function selectByVisibleText(select, textDesired) {
    select.findElements(By.tagName('option'))
    .then(options => {
        options.map(option => {
            option.getText().then(text => {
                if (text == textDesired)
                    option.click();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone stuck on this, here is how I did it for a `<select>` option:

```
<select id='mySelection'>
   <option value='0'>Hello</option>
   <option value='1'>Everybody</option>
   <option value='2'>Got</option>
   <option value='3'>It</option>
</select>
```

In Selenium for NodeJS, you would grab the `It` `<option>`:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();


driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('mySelection')).sendKeys('It');
```

When you `.sendKeys()` for the option it has to equal the text displayed to the user in the dropdown.

In your case just grab the parent element then `sendKeys()` for the child element.

Comment: Yeah this didn't work for me, sendKeys() is basically sending values but the parent element isn't a field or something that actually accepts values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```js
<select id='mySelection'>
   <option value='cat'>Cat!</option>
   <option value='dog'>Dog!</option>
   <option value='rat'>Rat!</option>
</select>
```

You can use the method `sendKeys` passing either the value or the text

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('mySelection')).sendKeys('Rat!');
```

or

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('mySelection')).sendKeys('rat');
```