# Getting dropdown values using selenium and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I have an requirement getting the all the options of a dropdown and I need to loop over those values and submit the form. So I need the list of dropdown values.

following code in java matches my exact requirement, but i need the same code in Javascript + selenium + Nodejs

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("height")));
List list = select.getOptions();
```

Is this possible to do in nodejs + selenium + javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041791/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-node-js/28643481#28643481

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stuck on this, heres how I did it for a option:

```
<select id='mySelection'>
   <option value='0'>Hello</option>
   <option value='1'>Everybody</option>
   <option value='2'>Got</option>
   <option value='3'>It</option>
</select>
```

In Selenium for NodeJS, you would grab the "It" :

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('mySelection')).sendKeys('3');
```

When you .sendKeys() for the option it has to equal the value=''

In your case just grab the parent element then sendKeys() for the child element.

Comment: Hello GARPdev , thanks for your answer and I have tried your solution but it works for one's and some times it's going to fail say example in my scenario there is need to fill the  address form by reading the csv file for multiple records at that time this solution is going to fail

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the elements

the example page is
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

```
let optionList = [];
  for (let index = 1; index < 99999; index++) {
    try{
      const optionValue = await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="cars"]/option[${index}]`));
      optionList.push(optionValue.getText());
    }
    catch {
      break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use Cheerio -

```
module.exports = {
    "login": function (browser) {
        var cheerio = require("cheerio")

        browser
            .url("http://www.wikipedia.org")
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .waitForElementVisible('select#searchLanguage', 1000)
            .source(function(result) { // .source() dump the page source in the variable
                $ = cheerio.load(result.value)
                var num_languages = $('select#searchLanguage option').length
                console.log('Wikipedia.org Languages: ' + num_languages);
            })
            .end();
    }
};
```

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041791/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-node-js/28643481#28643481) for the same.