# how to select a drop down value in selenium-webdriver with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to select a value from the drop down element in Node JS with 'selenium-webdriver' package and could not find any support for 'Select' options. In java we know that using Select class. But in this npm package, how can we select a value from drop down.

HTML code:

```
<select id="ivSearch:searchType" name="ivSearch:searchType" class="main" size="1">  
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
    <option value="3">value one</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">value two</option>
    <option value="96">value three</option>
    <option value="87">value four</option>
    <option value="4">value five</option>
    <option value="1">value six</option>
</select>
```

i need to select a value 'value four' from the drop down list and proceed. any help please.

in java i know it is like below, likewise how can it be in NodeJS?

```
Select lists = new Select(element);
lists.selectByValue("value four");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to select a dropdown value in selenium webdriver using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041791/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-node-js)